# Jboss Developer Studio: Create a sample RESTful Web Service

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, web-services, jboss

I've just installed latest (8.1.0) Jboss Developer Studio with EAP on my Mac and I need to create Restful web service. Based on [official documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/3.3.0.Final/en/resful_web_services_user_guide/html_single/), I should be able to `Create a sample RESTful Web Service` in my `Dynamic Web Project`. But I don't see that option, only SOAP web service:[image]